# 'sudo apt-get update' failure

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, failed-installation

Below is the o/p for `sudo apt-get update`:

```
/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]
Err:1 http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:2 http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Err:2 http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:3 http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:3 http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <Pub_key_here>
E: The repository 'http://01.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

All `install` commands failing because of this I believe.

I would just like to reset things back to normal as I messed this while uninstalling virtualbox,kubectl. I was just getting familiar with that. Experiment back fired.

I've tried replacing `sources.list` using [this](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php) among other things I tried.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a public key to your keyring with the command like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/985376/767905):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

Then you should run `sudo apt-get update` normally.

Comment: Perfect! Problem resolved. Now the update,upgrade works fine. Will check the 'install' too and update how it goes. Thanks.